# Nested popup in jquery

Tags: jquery, popup

My requirement is.

I have one document button in a page .

When clicks on the document button a new pop will open with all the documents in table format
with EDIT and DELETE button.

When user clicks o the EDIT again we needs to show the document in new pop now I'm using simple modal pop up http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/ which is not support multiple popup . please suggest the jquery popup which supports multiple popups

Comment: Please share your work so far, do not expect complete solutions from a spec. This is a Q and A site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be more useful to take another approach.
A popup inside a popup is not very user friendly.

I suggest the following:

when clicking on the edit or delete button, replace the content inside the pop up.